# How does frequency-division multiplexing deal with overlaps?

Tags: broadcast

As I understand it, FDM uses separate frequency for each channel, thus A will transmit data, for instance, every two seconds and B every three seconds.

But, what will be delivered on the wire in the overlapping times, after 6, 12, 18 seconds in my example?

Does the multiplexer sends data from both channels? If so, how could someone distinguish between the senders? And if they are marked, what's the point of the frequency here?

Comment: What you're describing is time division multiplexing, although your description is a little off.  FDM uses subcarriers for each channel.  A and B can transmit simultaneously because they use different carrier frequencies.

Comment: This also might help: http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-fdm-and-tdm/

Answer (score 1):

Frequency-division multiplexing uses multiple frequencies/channels/bands to use a single medium for multiple messages simultaneously. Usually, the transmission is modulated onto a *carrier frequency* - think of radio broadcasting with many stations. For optical transmissions, *wavelength-division multiplexing* means the same thing.

> A will transmit data, for instance, every two seconds and B every three seconds.

describes *time-division* multiplex (or tries to). With TDM, there's a strict 'plan' for who is allowed to send for any particular point in time. There can be no overlap. It's either 'one of two stations sends for 2.5 seconds every five seconds' or 'station A sends for two seconds every five seconds, station B sends for three seconds every five seconds' (or any other deterministic scheme).

Probably needless to say, in frequency-division multiplex there can't be any overlap either. Each channel needs its own restricted frequency band, usually with a narrow "guard" band in between channels (e.g. with xDSL). When FDM is used for duplexing a single channel (simultaneous traffic in both directions on different frequency bands) it's often called *frequency-division duplex*.

Sometimes FDM channels do overlap (e.g. with wifi), so adjacent channels can't be used simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You had it up until 'thus'.
Seperate Frequencies - think violin and tuba.  They can play at the same time, their frequencies don't overlap, you can tell them apart.
As far as rate goes, that is determined by the signal 'bandwidth' plus other added  tricks like shifting the amplitude.